# Why did my JavaCL only detect the integrated graphics card?

Tags: java, opencl, nvidia

I have some such code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    CLContext context = JavaCL.createBestContext();
    CLQueue queue = context.createDefaultQueue();
    ByteOrder byteOrder = context.getByteOrder();

    System.out.println(context.getDeviceCount() + "\n" + context.getDevices()[0].createSignature());
}
```

After output I get this:

> 1
>
> Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630|Intel(R) Corporation|26.20.100.7263|FULL_PROFILE

Why is this so? (My discrete graphics card is GTX1080)

Answer (score 0):

I found NVIDIA CUDA platform and my GTX1080, but I dont understand how do create context of NVIDIA CUDA platform.

Added this code to past realise

```
CLPlatform[] platforms = JavaCL.listPlatforms();
for (int i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(platforms[i].getName());
    System.out.println(platforms[i].getBestDevice());
}
```

And I got it in output:

> NVIDIA CUDA
>
> GeForce GTX 1080 (NVIDIA CUDA)
>
> Intel(R) OpenCL
>
> Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (Intel(R) OpenCL)